# Get Adjacency matrix from a Shapefile

Tags: python, matlab, networkx, shapefile, adjacency-matrix

I have a folder containing shapefiles about **British Power Grid Network**.
I need to extract an **adjacency matrix** of this network from tese files.
As I have no experience with shapefiles I need a clear explaination of what to do to get such matrix.

By Adjacency Matrix I mean a squared matrix with as many dimensions as the number of the nodes of the Network and that has zeros in cells referring to two nodes that are not connected and has ones in cells referring to two nodes that are connected. I need such Matrix because I want to test an epidemiological system on this Network, which is English National Power Grid.

I tried running this code on Python:

```
    import networkx as nx
import pickle as serializer
#from osgeo import ogr
#import gdal
#import graphviz as pgv
G=nx.read_shp('NationalGrid-ElecTrans-MT-2012_Nodes.shp')
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
nx.draw(G)
#nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
#nx.degree(G)
#nx.density(G)
#nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
with open('some_file3.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump( A, f)
```

but now I don't know how to use the output, which I am attaching.
https://ufile.io/3917f

Comment: Is this file 'some_file3.txt'? By 'I don't know how to use the output', you mean this file or the adjacency_matrix? If you mean the file, it is not meant to be used, it is meant to be saved to disk in order to be loaded later. You need to run whatever analysis you need to perform on 'A'. Your question is not clear, please read [guide lines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking questions.

Comment: The output is not a mathematically defined adjacency matrix, so I cannot read it. As you said, it is coded. Actually I need to import the adjacency matrix in Matlab but if I try to import the .txt file it is not recognized as a matrix.
So, if I want to import this matrix in Matlab what can I do?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`nx.adj_matrix(G)` returns `SciPy sparse matrix`, You probably need DataFrame or array. using `nx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts(G)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_cycle([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_cycle([33,3,34,35])
A = pd.DataFrame(nx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts(G)).fillna(0).replace([{}],1)
out: 

    1   2   3   4   5   33  34  35
1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
4   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
33  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
34  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
35  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

or better:

```
A = nx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_dataframe(K)
```

if you need numpy array you can get values by `A.values`, and if you need numpy matrix:

```
A = nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(K)
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/eOSq9Q
this is what happens when I run the command.
As you can see I have no experience with python.

Comment: What you get after loading shapefile? Can you do G.edges(data=true)?

Comment: @AurelioPalacardo It seems that the shapefile you are loading has only points, as the name suggests (`NationalGrid-ElecTrans-MT-2012_Nodes.shp`). In that case, you will end up with a graph containing only nodes without any edge!! So basically there is nothing to export. You should get the right shapefile which contains `Lines`.

Comment: You are right. I found the right shapefile, it has around 2k nodes so it will take a long time to run.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fhzbJk
I think there is some problem with the matrix dimensions and the memory.
What can I do?

Comment: 2k node, mean that there is no edge? then again will end up with a graph with no edge!
Do you get memory error when loading the shapefile or when trying to get adjacency matrix? If latter is the case, that's the reason why you get sparse matrix with `nx.adj_matrix(G)`. a full matrix is a very inefficient way of storing graphs. If for instance you have a graph with 2k edges, sparse matrix has 2k entries, but full matrix has 4M entries, most of them zeros.

Comment: 2k node doesnt mean there is no edge. Now I am using the right shapefile with edges.
It is the latter case. 
So I have to use `nx.adj_matrix(G)` to get the sparse matrix and then what can I do to import it in Matlab?

Comment: I am not familiar with Matlab. I think there should be some other way  for importing data in Matlab. you can use `nx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts(G)` and then convert the resulting dictionary to `json` for example if you know how to read in json in Matlab.

Comment: @AurelioPalacardo Networkx also supports saving graphs in a variety of standard formats including `GraphML`,  `GEXF`, `GML`, etc. there are many options to export data from Networkx, you may find what you need by looking into [Reading and writing graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite.html) and [Converting to and from other data formats](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html).